# How to re-infer datatypes on existing polars dataframe?

Tags: python, csv, schema, python-polars

I have the following problem:

I have a csv-file with faulty values (strings instead of integers) in some rows. To remedy that, I read it into polars and filter the dataframe.

To be able to read it, I have to set `infer_schema_length = 0`, since otherwise the read would fail. This reads every column as a string, though. How would I re-infer the data types/schema of the corrected dataframe? I'd like to try to avoid setting every column individually, as there are a lot.

I unfortunately can't edit the csv itself.

```
ids_df = pl.read_csv(dataset_path, infer_schema_length=0)

filtered_df = ids_df.filter(~(pl.col("Label") == "Label"))

filtered_df.dtypes

[Utf8,
 Utf8,
 Utf8,
 Utf8,
 Utf8,
 Utf8,
 Utf8,
 Utf8,
 Utf8,
 Utf8,
 ...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you check it with `scan_csv`? e.g. `pl.scan_csv(dataset_path).schema`

Comment: @jqurious this works initially, but still fails as soon as I fetch everything.

Comment: I mean like: `filtered_df.cast( pl.scan_csv(..).schema )` - but I'm not sure if I am understanding the issue correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify, I was completely misunderstanding the issue. Thanks to @SenseiH for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Polars has this funtionality yet, but I think I found a valid way to solve your problem:

```
from io import BytesIO
import polars as pl
dataset_path = "./test_data.csv"
ids_df = pl.read_csv(dataset_path, infer_schema_length=0)
print("ids_df",ids_df)

filtered_df = ids_df.filter(~(pl.col("Label") == "Label"))
print("filtered_df", filtered_df)

# Save data to memory as a IO stream
bytes_io = BytesIO()
filtered_df.write_csv(bytes_io)

# Read from IO stream with infer_schema_lenth != 0
new_df = pl.read_csv(bytes_io)
print("new_df", new_df)
bytes_io.close()
```

[image: output]

Comment: I think you can also `pl.read_csv(pl.read_csv().filter().write_csv().encode())` instead of having to use `io.BytesIO` manually.

Comment: @jqurious thanks for both of your inputs, they both work perfectly!

Comment: To build on the solution from @jqurious...
If the DataFrame is large, only write as many rows as is used to infer the schema with `read_csv` (current default is 100)

`inferred_schema = pl.read_csv(filtered_df.head(100).write_csv().encode()).schema`
followed by
`new_df = df.cast(inferred_schema)`